# Raspberry Pi 3 and V4L2 C++ Capture Code for JPEGs

Tags: camera, raspicam, c++, raspbian-stretch, v4l2

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest Raspbian Stretch, and the Sony 8MB official camera.

I can save a good looking JPEG with the following commands:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=2592,height=1944,pixelformat=3
v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap=3 --stream-count=1 --stream-to=somefile.jpg
```

I can list all formats with this command:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YU12'
    Name        : Planar YUV 4:2:0
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 3280x2464 with step 2/2

    ...

    Index       : 3
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'JPEG' (compressed)
    Name        : JFIF JPEG
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 3280x2464 with step 2/2
```

Now I want to translate the v4l2-ctl capture of a JPEG to C++ / Qt5 with libv4l2. My code is shown below and whenever I run it on the Pi, I get the following error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ./v4l2-test 
Begin Capture
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Operation not permitted
```

C++ Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

// C++ / V4L2 Includes
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <fcntl.h>              /* low-level i/o */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

// Debugging
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Begin Capture";

    int fd;
    if((fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR)) < 0){
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct v4l2_capability cap;
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_QUERYCAP");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE)){
        fprintf(stderr, "The device does not handle single-planar video capture.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct v4l2_format format;
    format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_JPEG;
    format.fmt.pix.width = 2592;
    format.fmt.pix.height = 1944;

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &format) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_S_FMT");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct v4l2_requestbuffers bufrequest;
    bufrequest.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    bufrequest.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    bufrequest.count = 1;

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &bufrequest) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_REQBUFS");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct v4l2_buffer bufferinfo;
    memset(&bufferinfo, 0, sizeof(bufferinfo));

    bufferinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    bufferinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    bufferinfo.index = 0;

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_QUERYBUF");
        exit(1);
    }

    void* buffer_start = mmap(
                NULL,
                bufferinfo.length,
                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                MAP_SHARED,
                fd,
                bufferinfo.m.offset
                );

    if(buffer_start == MAP_FAILED){
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(buffer_start, 0, bufferinfo.length);

    // Activate streaming
    int type = bufferinfo.type;
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_STREAMON");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Here is where you typically start two loops:
     * - One which runs for as long as you want to
     *   capture frames (shoot the video).
     * - One which iterates over your buffers everytime. */

    bool capture_is_running = true;
    while(capture_is_running){
        for(int i = 0; i < bufrequest.count; i++){

            // Put the buffer in the incoming queue.
            if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
                perror("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                exit(1);
            }

            // The buffer's waiting in the outgoing queue.
            if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &bufferinfo) < 0){
                perror("VIDIOC_QBUF");
                exit(1);
            }

        }

    }

    // Deactivate streaming
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type) < 0){
        perror("VIDIOC_STREAMOFF");
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    return a.exec();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The camera works and I run as root, but for some reason I get "Permission Denied". I appreciate any help - thanks.

UPDATE - The exact error I see is shown below as well as the terminal output showing that "root" is in the "video" group

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# groups root
root : root video
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ./v4l2-test 
Begin Capture
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Operation not permitted
```

UPDATE: Running 'file' on the v4l2-ctl saved image shows the 2592x1944 sized frame:

```
root@raspberrypi:/tmp# file somefile.jpg 
somefile.jpg: JPEG image data, Exif standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=9, height=0, model=imx219, xresolution=130, yresolution=138, resolutionunit=2, datetime=1970:01:01 00:00:00, width=0], baseline, precision 8, 2592x1944, frames 3
```

UPDATE: Here is a paste of the complete STRACE output of all commands:

```
https://zerobin.net/?84fee190a4a904a0#ZZOwDe7ftBKjpqpP/lPfnTMPrUlILyJaCCCyunO6aug=
```

UPDATE: Linking step of application compilation

```
/home/me/Desktop/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/home/me/Desktop/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -o v4l2-test main.o   -lrt -lpthread -ldl -latomic
```

UPDATE: I removed my S_FMT ioctl, but the issue still continues:

```
    struct v4l2_format format;
    format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_JPEG;
    // 3280x2464
    format.fmt.pix.width = 3280;
    format.fmt.pix.height = 2464;

//    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &format) < 0){
//        perror("VIDIOC_S_FMT");
//        exit(1);
//    }

    struct v4l2_requestbuffers bufrequest;
    bufrequest.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    bufrequest.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    bufrequest.count = 1;
```

UPDATE: I just checked dmesg again I'm seeing the following error - however Google has not turned up anything so far...

```
Jan 06 01:40:19 raspberrypi kernel: video0: VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
Jan 06 01:40:19 raspberrypi kernel: video0: VIDIOC_S_FMT
Jan 06 01:40:19 raspberrypi kernel: video0: VIDIOC_REQBUFS
Jan 06 01:40:19 raspberrypi kernel: video0: VIDIOC_QUERYBUF
Jan 06 01:40:20 raspberrypi kernel: bcm2835-v4l2: Failed to enable capture port - error -28. Disabling camera port again
Jan 06 01:40:20 raspberrypi kernel: video0: VIDIOC_STREAMON: error -1
```

UPDATE: Per suggestion - I tried increasing the buffer count to 3 - but it did not help:

```
struct v4l2_requestbuffers bufrequest;
bufrequest.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
bufrequest.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
bufrequest.count = 3;

if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &bufrequest) < 0){
    perror("VIDIOC_REQBUFS");
    exit(1);
}

fprintf(stderr,"Buffer Request is for 3 buffers...\n");
```

Comment: Your program runs fine for me (my different camera so different resolution, added loop exit condition, added printout to confirm buffers). Questions (please edit your post to clarify): 1. Can you check that your user `pi` is in `video` according to `/etc/group`? Chances are it is as that's the Raspbian default and if it weren't you'd get `open: Permission denied`, but good to confirm. 2. In your post you wrote you're getting `Operation not permitted` (EPERM) but at the end you said "Permission Denied" (EACCES) in quotes. Could you clarify? 3. `guvcview` and `cheese` also work fine as non-root?

Comment: @jdonald - both root and pi are in the video group. Also, the error is "Operation not permitted", when the VIDIOC_STREAMON ioctl is executed. The weird thing I don't understand is that the v4l2-ctl application successfully saves a good looking JPEG from both users.

Comment: Thanks. I looked through [bcm2835-camera.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/bcm2835-camera.c) and [v4l2-ioctl.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ioctl.c) but it's unlikely you're hitting either of those EPERM cases. Can you compare the **strace** output of `v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap...` vs your program (starting from `open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR)` down to `VIDIOC_STREAMON`)? My USB camera works in both cases, but I notice that v4l2-ctl swaps the order of the first VIDIOC_QBUF with VIDIOC_STREAMON.

Comment: @jdonald - thank you for the help. Your suggestion to check strace allowed me to see the libc errors I've updated my post with. I cross compiled the app with the official Raspberry Pi toolchain and a Buildroot build. It seems those files do not exist in my buildroot build however. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Those errors are just localization for `perror()` and those happen after the `EPERM` anyway. I also realized that ordering of VIODIC_QBUF/VIDIOC_STREAMON may be an artifact of strace order inaccuracy. Next: `somefile.jpg` is viewable, but if you run `file somefile.jpg` is it the requested resolution 2592x1944? And 2592x1944 is for Camera Module V1 but your `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` indicates  this is Camera Module V2 (3280x2464), plus you said it's the Sony module. Strange if wrong resolution has different behavior on root vs `video`, but might as well fix your code and rule it out?

Comment: If that makes no difference, other troubleshooting in order: 1. Remove Qt-linking from your program. Quick to do and rules out setup artifacts from Qt initialization. 2. Provide full strace logs for all three cmds (--set-fmt-video, --stream-mmap, v4l2-test). This helps identify any mismatch in length, colorspace. Hopefully fits within Stack Exchange's limits or else use a pastebin. 3. To determine if this is JPEG-specific, carry out the same tests with pixelformat=0, YUV. Note to view a streamed image: `sudo apt install imagemagick; display -size 3280x2464 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 somefile.yuv`

Comment: I changed the resolution in my C++ app to 3280x2464 , but I see the same error. I also removed all Qt linkage, unfortunately that did not help either. I collected full strace output for the three commands and put them in a pastebin linked in the post. I also switched the format to YUV, and the v4l2 was still able to capture. The imagemagick display command shows an image ( though the coloring is off ).

Comment: Sorry that 1 and 3 didn't do anything but rule out some hunches. On any strangeness in your strace log: The garbage input values into VIDIOC_S_FMT are probably fine (it corrects them in the output), but you can set `format.fmt.pix.{bytesperline,colorspace,sizeimage}` manually just to be sure. Most suspicious: `lib{EGL,libbcm_host,libvcos,libvchiq_arm}.so`; can you remove *all* linked libraries (even `libv4l2`, which you're not actually using!) and compile the .cpp by itself? Lastly, why does your strace log say `root@raspberrypi`? I thought the program failed as `pi` but worked as `root`.

Comment: You can disregard the `root@raspberrypi` question. Looking at this again, I misunderstood your original post regarding root. I thought you were saying your program works as root but not a regular user, but now I see that `v4l2-test` fails for both `pi` and `root`. 6. Unexpected `O_LARGEFILE` flag: if something is passing `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` you can remove it, although that's probably benign (works on my system regardless). 7. Try removing the **VIDIOC_S_FMT** step from your source code. That'll make it very similar to stream-mmap, and it still works for me.

Comment: Yes the application does fail for both pi and root in the same way. Thanks for bringing up the fact that the libraries were still linked, I had to add CONFIG -= qt to my qmake file and now those libs are removed. I updated my post with the linking step of the compilation. Unfortunately, the issue persists.

Comment: Also, I removed the S_FMT, but it didn't help. Thanks for your ideas - if you have any more I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I found this new message in dmesg: "Jan 06 01:40:20 raspberrypi kernel: bcm2835-v4l2: Failed to enable capture port - error -28. Disabling camera port again". Googling hasn't turned up anything so far...

Comment: Ahh should have thought to check dmesg. The code that causes that error is in [bcm2835-camera.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/bcm2835-camera.c) and mmal-vchiq.c. Could you try with `bufrequest.count = 3;` instead of 1? If that works, I'll write up a full explanation.

Comment: Hi @jdonald - I put "bufrequest.count = 3;" in my code but I still see the error. We are definitely getting closer :)

Comment: Yeah I think we were on the right track, just need to queue the three buffers as well. I fixed up your program and made it output jpeg files. Could you try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jdonald/a23ad36ee270a5943ca2035328530a53) that allocates all three buffers? If that gives you any issues, try [this one](https://gist.github.com/jdonald/803c03432ef1b8e291379213d73f1669) as well. These successfully save JPEGs on my USB webcam. Explanation coming, provided something works!

Comment: The first gist works! Thank you. Please writeup an answer so I can award the bounty, it expires in 15 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a case of a program that runs without error on some cameras (such as mine), but gives an error specifically with Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2. We can track this down starting with the dmesg error:

> `Jan 06 01:40:20 raspberrypi kernel: bcm2835-v4l2: Failed to enable capture port - error -28. Disabling camera port again`

Error 28 (ENOSPC) is "No space left on device". Grepping the kernel, the code flagging this error is in [bcm2835/mmal-vchiq.cpp](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/mmal-vchiq.c):

```
    /* ensure there are enough buffers queued to cover the buffer headers */
    if (port->buffer_cb != NULL) {
        hdr_count = 0;
        list_for_each(buf_head, &port->buffers) {
            hdr_count++;
        }
        if (hdr_count < port->current_buffer.num)
            return -ENOSPC;
    }
```

So this driver expects all buffers to have been allocated by the time `VIDIOC_STREAMON` is called. That wasn't the case in the original code, while you'll see that `VIDIOC_QBUF` comes before `VIDIOC_STREAMON` in the strace log for `v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap...` which does work.

However, there's an additional mismatch in `v4l2-test.cpp`'s strace log:

```
ioctl(3, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, {count=1, type=V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, memory=V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP}) = 0 ({count=3})
```

That means although the program requests a single buffer, V4L2 is insisting on three buffers! Perhaps the code was originally designed for a different camera, one like my own that permits `bufrequest.count = 1` as is.

This [revised program](https://gist.github.com/jdonald/a23ad36ee270a5943ca2035328530a53) creates a loop to prepare all three buffers. To allocate and queue each one, we do VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, mmap(), then VIDIOC_QBUF. Once all buffers are set up, we can start the loop that pulls camera images from the circular buffer.

Another way of looking at the revised code: it runs a sequence very similar to what's found in the strace log for `v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap...`. Comparing the strace logs did initially bring red herrings such as extra linked libraries or `O_LARGEFILE`. Fortunately once those were ruled out, the ordering of `ioctl()` and other system calls provided a useful reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting `VIDIOC_STREAMON: Operation not permitted` while using `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. Setting the `GPU memory` to a higher value, solved the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Pedro Lobito's response:

While I was testing at the command line using `v4l2-ctl` to perform test captures a lot of the supported pixelformats failed with "Operation not permitted" when trying for the full resolution supported by the chip 3280x2464 or just hang indefinitely with no error message and restarting the terminal and running any `v4l2-ctl` commands would from then on hang requiring a reboot of the Pi to fix.

But increasing the GPU memory in the "Raspberry Pi Configuration" to 256 fixed the "Operation not permitted" and the hanging for me.

I was using the Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2.